# Compiling selected Svelte components to CustomElements

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to build a front-end application using Svelte. I have a number of components that should be compiled as Custom Elements so that I can insert them dynamically, i.e. by doing:

```
<script>
   let my_html_string = '<p>Hello from <my-customelem/> something something</p>';
</script>

<div>
   {@html my_html_string}
</div>
```

This works fine as long as I set the global `customElement: true` in my rollup.config.js file.

However, this stops me using e.g. `svelte-router`, as it obviously won't compile to a custom element.

Is there a way to configure rollup to selectively compile certain elements to Custom Elements, while leaving the basic application (`App.svelte`, the svelte-router `Router`, `Link` etc. components) as standard Svelte components?

---

Update (more info):

The above component is (e.g.) `Page.svelte`. `CustomElement.svelte` is the component that should be compiled as a Custom Element.

I'm using svelte-routing (https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing) according to the instructions (nothing special).

My rollup.config is the default Svelte template version (with `customElement: true` set).

When I compile with `customElement: true` I get an 'Illegal Constructor' error (due to the svelte-routing `Router` component); when I remove `customElement: true`, I obviously don't get `CustomElement` compiled as a Custom Element (so can't insert it dynamically from an HTML string).

So, is there a way of selectively turning on `customElement: true` for just the Custom Elements?

Comment: Maybe you could improve the question by including your rollup-config, showing how svelte-router is used, and finally be clearly discribing how you build `my-customelm` and the unnamed component you've shown the code for. E.g. if my-customelem has been build as a web component, you wouldn't need to also to build the svelte component as customelement too. But that is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this example](https://github.com/jawish/svelte-customelement-rollup).

Also [my StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71310125/mixing-svelte-and-web-components-results-in-did-you-forget-the-customelement) contains such example. The following rollup config allows you to process both component types by using different files extensions: `*.svelte` for Svelte Components and `*.wc.svelte` for HTML5 custom elements.

```js
plugins: [
        ...

        /** Handle HTML5 Web Components **/
        svelte({
            include: /\.wc\.svelte$/,
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
                sourceMap: !production,
            }),
            compilerOptions: {
                customElement: true,
                // enable run-time checks when not in production
                dev: !production
            },
            // store CSS in JavaScript
            emitCss: false
        }),

        /** Handle Svelte Components **/
        svelte({
            exclude: /\.wc\.svelte$/,
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
                sourceMap: !production,
            }),
            compilerOptions: {
                customElement: false,
                // enable run-time checks when not in production
                dev: !production
            },
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file - better for performance
            emitCss: true
        }),

        ...
```

My only issue is, that it logs a warning for custom elements.